# how to skip blocks of text when writing file in python

Tags: python, file, input, output

Is it possible to use python to skip blocks of text when writing a file from another file?

For example lets say the input file is:

```
This is the file I would like to write this line
I would like to skip this line
and this one...
and this one...
and this one...
but I want to write this one
and this one...
```

How can I write a script that allows me to skip certain lines that differ in content and size which resumes writing the lines to another file once it recognizes a certain line?

My code reads through the lines, doesn't write duplicate lines and performs some operation on the line by using dictionaries and regex.

Comment: That entirely depends on _why_ you want to skip those lines.  There needs to be some codeable _rule_ to select some lines and not others.  Assuming you have that rule, this program becomes pretty simple really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def is_wanted(line):
    #
    # You have to define this!
    #
    # return True to keep the line, or False to discard it

def copy_some_lines(infname, outfname, wanted_fn=is_wanted):
    with open(infname) as inf, open(outfname, "w") as outf:
        outf.writelines(line for line in inf if wanted_fn(line))

copy_some_lines("file_a.txt", "some_of_a.txt")
```

---

In order to extend this to multi-line blocks, you can implement a finite state machine like

[image]

which would turn into something like

```
class BlockState:
    GOOD_BLOCK = True
    BAD_BLOCK = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = self.GOOD_BLOCK

    def is_bad(self, line):
        # *** Implement this! ***
        # return True if line is bad

    def is_good(self, line):
        # *** Implement this! ***
        # return True if line is good

    def __call__(self, line):
        if self.state == self.GOOD_BLOCK:
            if self.is_bad(line):
                self.state = self.BAD_BLOCK
        else:
            if self.is_good(line):
                self.state = self.GOOD_BLOCK
        return self.state
```

then

```
copy_some_lines("file_a.txt", "some_of_a.txt", BlockState())
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code:

```
# Open input and output files, and declare the unwanted function
for line in file1:
    if unwanted(line):
        continue
    file2.write(line)
# Close files etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line, and have control on each line you read:

```
with open(<your_file>, 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        # skip this line
        # but not this one
```

Note that if you want to read all lines despite the content and only then manipulate it, you can:

```
with open(<your_file>) as fil:
    lines = fil.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SIZE_TO_SKIP = ?
CONTENT_TO_SKIP = "skip it"

with open("my/input/file") as input_file:
    with open("my/output/file",'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if len(line)!=SIZE_TO_SKIP and line!=CONTENT_TO_SKIP:
                output_file.write(line)
```